Hanging Olympic Rings
So I read the "Advice on hanging gymnastic rings in garage rafters?" and I'm not satisfied with the responses. It's not that they weren't good it's just I still think it can be done safely and want to pose a question.
My specific space is a basement apartment with 2 x 6 inch oak joists 16 inch on center. I have a two ideas of installation.
1.) Span 3 joists with five 3/8"x4" lag screws through the 2"x6"(as a surface cleat). The ring hanger is attached to the 2"x6" with five 3/8" screws as well.
2.) Span 2 joists but use blocking 4 (2 x 4)'s (Oak) installed in a vertical manner using 3 inch lag screws drilled in from the other side of the joist on each side to hold up each 2 x 4's. Then using 5/8's threaded rod to run through the board and have a flat washer to lock washer to nut at the top. Then doing the same at the bottom.
Let me know if either is viable and if not a possible solution.


Oak joists would be pretty unusual for anywhere in North America. More likely pine, which would change the tolerances somewhat.

Oak is an unusual wood for structural members.  The free span of the joists is important.   Since very few of us are structural engineers(if any) and this can be a safety(break your neck) concern/structural(break joists) concern, we are not the best people to ask.  I prefer to mount from the top of the joists, than from the bottom for greater holding, but guessing your SO will have words if in the kitchen or any other room.

When you say, “apartment”, does that mean a rental? (If so, there are often constraints on what you can do.)

Old pine/spruce will have a dark colour close to oak, instead of the almost white of new pine/spruce.
